# one-to-many relationship saves foreign key as NULL in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, foreign-keys

I am trying to define a one-to-many relationship between my two table in Entity Framework in .net 3.5.

**City Table**

```
CityId
CityName
```

**Employee Table**

```
 EmployeeId
 EmployeeName
 RegistrationDate
 FK_CityID
```

I am trying to insert Data in Employee all data inserted Perfectly but **FK_CityID is instred NULL**.

Insert Button click Code
       DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 12, 12);

```
    EmployeeService es = new EmployeeService();
    CityService cs = new CityService();
    Payroll.Entities.Employee e1 = new Payroll.Entities.Employee();

    Payroll.Entities.City city1 = cs.SelectCity(Convert.ToInt32(cmbCity.SelectedItem.Value));

    e1.FK_CityID = city1;
    e1 = Payroll.Entities.Employee.CreateEmployee(0, "Archana",dt);
    es.AddEmpoyee(e1);
```

In **e1.City** I am Passing whole object that is **city1**(object of city) and it is passing Perfectly but **In database it will save NULL**

**MyService Class is**

```
public string AddEmpoyee(Payroll.Entities.Employee e1)
        {
            //DAO
            Payroll_DAO payrollDAO = new Payroll_DAO();
            payrollDAO.AddToEmployee(e1);
            payrollDAO.SaveChanges();
            return "SUCCESS";
        }
```

I am not getting where I am wrong...

Comment: Open up your SQL Profiler and see, What are the values getting passed, when you save!. Or put a put a break point at es.AddEmployee(e1) and see the fields of e1.

Comment: I put a break point at **es.AddEmployee(e1)**.. I am not getting value in **FK_CityID**. but insted of that i am getting **cityReference**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I got the solution..

```
Payroll.Entities.City city1 = new Payroll.Entities.City();
city1 = cs.SelectCity(Convert.ToInt64(cmbCity.SelectedItem.Value));

e1.EmployeeName = "Archana";
e1.RegistrationDate= dt;
e1.FK_CityID = city1;

es.AddEmpoyee(e1);
```